# Redirect from Wordpress to rails app if rails session == true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, session, redirect

So, I have a wordpress on one hand and a rails app on the other hand. My question comes here, if my user goes on the wordpress and is logged in on the rails app, I would like to redirect them to the rails app.

I can't put a page in the middle to play the balancer because of our friend google. I'm scared to loose my rank because of the redirection (and a new url).

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing session data between rails and wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385412/sharing-session-data-between-rails-and-wordpress)

Comment: Look at this same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385412/sharing-session-data-between-rails-and-wordpress